# Checking whether the user is logged in or not into the Appstore programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

My requirement is that I need to check that a user is logged in into the store or not. On that basis I need to implement some functionality. 
Please send me some documentation link if it is not possible to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. There is no API to learn anything about the user and their iTunes account. There is no link for this because there is nothing to link to.